# Eclipse 4.2.1 - Avd running but not receiving app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Eclipse is in another hard drive (e:). While avd are in c:/Users/Myname/Android.
Problem is that when I run as android application, nothing happens, though the emulator is running. The app is working on the physical phone. I've read several answers, all vague. Help?

Comment: Post the logcat and also the console output.

Comment: what your console says...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the Android Debug Bridge (adb) isn't running or isn't correctly running. Try running

```
adb devices
```

If your emulator is not listed, try running

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Note that adb is installed in the `platform-tools` subdirectory within your android sdk installation.

Comment: Thanks flight, I've just typed adb in the command line and that kinda woke up the system.

Comment: If this has fixed your problem, please remember to accept the answer.